# add CSS files to Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I added a navbar.html.eex to my layout folder and this template is rendered from app.html.eex `<%= render "navbar.html", conn: @conn, current_user: @current_user %>`

in app.css:

`@import 'navbar.css';`

and it should point to my file: assets/css/navbar.css

But the file does not load, in my browser console I get: `GET http://localhost:4000/css/navbar.css net::ERR_ABORTED` with a 404 error.

I come from the Rails world and that's how I was used to do but maybe there is another way of doing it in Phoenix. I can't find a nice doc about managing css files in Phoenix so if anybody has some readings to recommend ! I'll be grateful !

Comment: where did you put your css assets?

Comment: They are all in assets/css (Phoenix 1.3)

Comment: in  `web/static/assets` ? take a look at the docs here: http://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets

Comment: I added an answer for 2022 / Phoenix 1.6, now that Phoenix uses esbuild: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591398/10307728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoenix uses [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) which builds your assets. By default, it will copy everything in your */web/static/assets/* directory to */priv/static*. Check out the [Phoenix Static Assets](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets) documentation for more information.

**Update - Phoenix version 1.6**

Please refer to this SO post for newer version: [add CSS files to Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720445/add-css-files-to-phoenix/71591398#71591398)

Comment: This is not a solution as of Phoenix 1.6, I posted an up-to-date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71591398/10307728

Answer (score 3):

In Phoenix, all css files are/should be stored in the `priv\static\css` folder. In order to add your custom css, add the css file to the folder above then head to the `lib\foldername_web\templates\layout` and edit the `app.html.eex` file located there. You will see a line between the head tags that looks like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>"/>
```

Edit the text and rename it to the css file you created or added so that the line looks like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/my-css.css") %>"/>
```

Your page should look different now. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

## Updated for 2022 - Phoenix version 1.6

*As of writing, Phoenix (version 1.6) uses [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/). You can read about asset management in [the phoenix documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/asset_management.html), specifically, you may want to read [the section about CSS](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/asset_management.html#css); here's an excerpt:*

> #### `esbuild` has basic support for CSS. If you import a `.css` file at the top of your main `.js` file, `esbuild` will also bundle it, and write it to the same directory as your final `app.js`.

You'll notice `import "../css/app.css"` in `app.js` in projects created with [`mix phx.new`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.New.html).

---

#### Custom CSS when using [Tailwind CSS with Phoenix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/phoenix)

If you followed the [official guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/phoenix) to setup Tailwind with Phoenix 1.6, `esbuild` will bundle your JS to `priv/static/assets/app.js` and any CSS files you import in `app.js` to `priv/static/assets/app.css`. The problem is, `tailwind` will then overwrite `priv/static/assets/app.css` and you'll lose whatever custom styles you imported in `app.js`.

To get around this, you could change the name of the output file either `esbuild` or `tailwind` generates in `config/config.exs` and change all references to it, or you could paste your custom CSS directly into `app.css`, optionally within a [`tailwind` `@layer` directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer) if you want modifiers and tree-shaking.

Answer (score 1):

this post might help you with the configuration.

https://elixirforum.com/t/boostrap-4-sass-installation-in-phoenix-1-3/10139?source_topic_id=10804

and will hopefully resolve your issues. I had the same issue when setting up my front-end and it helped me out

Answer (score 1):

All .css files inside assets/css will be imported automatically. No need to import them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after I read the docs I realised Pheonix uses Brunch and gather CSS in a big app.css file in priv/static. No import needed like in Rails.